# Redis Pub/Sub vs Node.JS EventEmitter for only-once processed events

Tags: node.js, express, events, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm new to the concept of event-driven applications and pub-sub in general, and I'm struggling to find the best way to approach an issue with a web app that I'm currently building with Node.JS and Express.

When a new user signs up, I want to emit a new event called `user-signed-up` so that processing of things like sending registration emails can happen away from the main service.  The app needs to be open to horizontal scaling in future, which is why I started leaning towards Redis pub-sub, but as far as my understanding goes the messages from Redis would then be processed by every node in the server cluster, which I don't want to happen for specific events (e.g. I don't want registration emails to be sent by every subscriber; only once).

That leads me to think that the best solution is to use Redis for events that need to be shared across the entire cluster, but EventEmitter for events that should only be processed once so that they're handled by the same Node instance that it was generated on.

My question is whether this is the best approach, or whether there's a better way with Redis (either only sending a message to one subscriber, or whether there's some way of conditionally subscribing one node in the cluster to a specific channel to handle events that should only be dealt with once).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You question is too broad to give specific advise. I can however provide some input that might help you make a decision.

In general, `EventEmitter` is a good way to communicate within a single Node.js process. You have to consider what happens when your process stops or crashes before handling the event. Your new user may never receive the registration e-mail.

Again, in general, Redis can be used to communicate between multiple processes.

If you want only one process to handle a specific event, you can create a ''message queue'' with Redis. You can do this with a list in Redis. You RPUSH new events to the end of the list and your worker processes LPOP events from the beginning of the list. You can use PUB/SUB to notify workers when new events are available. Also in this setup, you have to consider what happens when your worker process stops or crashes after LPOP'ing the event but before handling the event. Your new user may never receive the registration e-mail.

If you have experience with traditional SQL databases, you can also consider using a SQL database instead of Redis. For example PostgreSQL has [NOTIFY/LISTEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html) which is similar to PUB/SUB.